# How to make ATG dynamo admin server password not expire

Tags: server, passwords, admin, atg, oracle-commerce

I've seen various posts that help you reset the password when it expires (using various means ACC, DB update etc). But, is there a way you can make the admin password never expire? We have lot of automation built around this admin interface and it is turning out to be a hassle every time this password had to be changed. It would be nice if we can make the password never expire.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `enabled` property on `/atg/dynamo/security/passwordchecker/ExpiredPasswordAdminService/` to `false`.

Below is a sample `ExpiredPasswordAdminService.properties` file.  You will need to create this in the appropriate configuration layer:

```
$class=atg.security.ExpiredPasswordAdminService

# Enable/Disable the password expiration service
enabled=false
```